# Using WebSQL in AngularJs Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, web-sql, angular-services

I am building a hybrid mobile app using cordova and AngularJs. I have setup a WebSQL to store data locally on my app. I am trying to abstract my WebSQL queries to an Angular service. However, whenever I make a call to method in the service from a controller, nothing gets returned. The results variable clearly returns data from the database when I do a console log on it. However it doesn't seem to return the data to my controller. I understand if you are using plain vanilla JS  or other frameworks with angular then the code needs to be wrapped inside $digest / $apply function. I'm not quite sure how to apply it in this instance since the $scope variable is not available inside Angular Services. Below is an example on what I am trying to achieve.

```
app.service('UserService', function(){

    this.getAll = function(){
        db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM users", [], function(tx, results){
            return results.rows;
        });
    }

});


app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, UserService){

    $scope.users = UserService.getAll();

});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a pretty easy service you can drop into your app

[Try this one](https://github.com/paulocaldeira17/angular-websql)

Comment: Thanks but i know about this plugin. But it is too simple for my project. I need the ability to write custom queries. Not sure if this plugin allows for that